# Jquery Datatable Sort Click Event in Table Header Not in Column Title Text

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I have this table which I implement the [Jquery-DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/)

and in that I have a Select All function that works well;

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" > All
      </label>
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

the problem is when I clicked the checkbox the sort event of table is also being performed. what I want is, when I click on the Text "All" or the Checkbox the sort event will **not** perform, instead, it will only perform as usual if the table header(outside the Text or Checkbox) and the Sort-Icon is clicked.

any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue by running this script (from [this](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/4412/sorting-issue-on-headers-when-checking-unchecking-checkboxes)) after initialization of Jquery-Datable to my table;

```
$('input').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

hope it will help someone someday.